# Access violation writing location... probably caused by mpi_get_processor_name function

Tags: compiler-errors, parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I ran into the following error message when I tried to establish my first intel visual fortran+ms-mpi program on the visual studio 2010 environment (IVF 2013, Windows 7 64-bit).

The error message is:

Unhandled exception at Ox001f3902 in HELLO.exe: OxC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000001e.

Pointed out by my compiler, the problem seemed associated with the function mpi_get_processor_name in line 7. Is it caused by my wrong declaration for the string variable, **name**?

Besides, I can successfully compile a C++ MPI sample code on the same machine. It is really weird to me that I cannot run a Fortran sample code with similar environment setting. Thanks for help.

The code looks like

```
1  PROGRAM hello
2   INCLUDE 'mpif.h'
3   INTEGER rank, size, ierror, len
4   CHARACTER(30) name
5   INTEGER id, nthreads
6   CALL mpi_init(ierror)                            ! start MPI
7   CALL mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world, size, ierror) ! get number of ranks
8   CALL mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world, rank, ierror) ! get rank
9   CALL mpi_get_processor_name(name,len,ierror)     ! get run-host name
10  nthreads = omp_get_num_threads()                 ! get number of threads
11  id = omp_get_thread_num()                        ! get thread
12  CALL mpi_finalize(ierror)                        ! terminate MPI
13 END PROGRAM hello                                 ! Fortran 90
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME` requires that `name` is an array of **at least** `MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME` characters, which at least in Open MPI is equal 256. The name written is padded on the right with empty characters up to position `MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME` and `len` is set to the actual name length. In your case `name` is most probably a stack variable and the padding characters overwrite the stack frame, thus the access violation.

Replace:

```
CHARACTER(30) name
```

with

```
CHARACTER(MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME) name
```